# How can I use AWK to sort this type of data into an array to use in BASH

Tags: bash, awk

The file looks something like this:

```
index:index.html
required:file2.1:file2.2
```

How do I get it into an array of index containing the string - `index.html`
and an array of required containing the strings - `file2.1` and `file2.2`. and be able to use it in bash?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: I know how to do it without `awk`, but I don't know how to do it with `awk`. Since `awk` is a requirement, I can't help you, sorry. Unless you're okay if I use `awk` in a comment line…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024) pointed, because you want bash arrays at the end, you can do the whole job with bash and you do not need awk. So, if it is part of your homework assignment, either explain the teacher that *you* found a better way or use something far less elegant and efficient as:

```
filename=<name-of-input-file>
a=($(awk -F: '$1 == "required" {for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1) printf $i" "}' $filename))
echo ${a[0]}
file2.1
echo ${a[1]}
file2.2
```

**Explanation:**

`a=(word1 word2 ...)` assigns bash array `a` with the listed words.

`$(command)` evaluates the bash command.

`awk -F: '$1 == "required" {for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1) printf $i" "}' data.txt` filters file `data.txt` with awk, using `:` as fields separator. If the first field is `required` it prints all other fields (`NF` is the number of fields), separating them by a space.

And of course, you can very easily adapt it to create the other bash array. I leave it to you as a way to verify that you got it well.

Comment: The data.txt file, I have to use a variable from Bash to set it. How do I do that without the awk confusing it for its own variable? This is what I have so far: a=($(awk -F: '$1 == "required" {for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1) printf $i" "}' ${1}"/README"))

Comment: Note that `a=( $(...) )` is an antipattern: the expansion of `$(...)` will be subject to word splitting and pathname expansion. The proper way to populate an array in this case is to use a `while read` loop or to use the builtin `mapfile`.

Comment: @Dan: edited my answer to show you how to use a bash variable for the input file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create bash arrays, you need to use bash, not awk:

```
declare -A req
declare -A arr
while IFS=: read a b c
do  
   if [ "$a" = "required" ]
   then 
      req[$b]=$c
   elif [ "$b" ]
   then
      arr[$a]=$b
   fi
done <file
```

With your sample input, this creates the two arrays that you asked for:

```
declare -A arr='([index]="index.html" )'
declare -A req='([file2.1]="file2.2" )'
```

#### How it works

Associative arrays have to be declared before use:

```
declare -A req
declare -A arr
```

The following starts a loop.  It reads the first three colon-separated fields from the input:

```
while IFS=: read a b c
do
```

If the first field is `required`, then this uses the second and third fields to create a new entry in array `req`:

```
   if [ "$a" = "required" ]
   then 
      req[$b]=$c
```

Otherwise, assuming a nonempty second field is present, this adds an entry to array `arr`:

```
   elif [ "$b" ]
   then
      arr[$a]=$b
   fi
```

The code below marks the end of the loop and indicates that loop input should be taken from file `file`:

```
done <file
```

Comment: Is there a way to make AWK output , for example, the "required:file2.1:file2.2" line to "file2.1 file2.2" and then get a bash loop to run for each of these strings?

Comment: Yes but, if it made `required:file2.1:file2.2` into `file2.1 file2.2`, how would you know that this is intended for the `required` array?

Comment: Besides, bash works with colon-separated values as well as awk does.  So, why do that?

Comment: I am hoping all of the files that are called README will have index displayed first and required displayed second. I am not sure but is it alright if I show you the homework assignment. :(

Comment: How do I use bash with colon separated values? I am really new at this. I barely managed to get what I have so far with this program.

Comment: _"How do I use bash with colon separated values?"_ You use the way that I showed in the answer.